# Centering things Vertically (and Horizontally)

Tags: html, css

Why is trying to align something in the center of the viewport (or wrapper) either vertically or horizontally (or both) so painful?

I have tried everything I could find in the past hour, from sites like W3Schools to S/O to MSDN - I just don't know how to do it. There has to be an easy way to do this. And WHY can you center a DIV horizontally like this: margin: 0 auto; but not vertically? And why can't you use that same approach with any other element on the page?

I have a one line sentence (testimonial) that i would like to center vertically and horizontally, how can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will center both horizontally and vertically and it works in all browsers including IE quirks mode.

```
div{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:red;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin-left:-100px; /* Negative half the width*/
    margin-top:-100px; /* Negative half the height */
}
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/Nt5PU/

Comment: @Hussein There is one issue with this solution: if the DIV height is larger than the viewport height, the top of the DIV will not be visible and you will not be able to scroll to it at all. @Josh's solution does not have this problem.

Comment: @sime It doesn't matter what the div height is, it will always center to the available window height. If window height is smaller then the actual div height, then naturally it will not look centered unless you expand windows height.

Comment: @Hussein The top of the DIV will not be visible. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/Nt5PU/2/ (reduce the page height and the first couple of rows will move outside the viewport, and you will not be able to scroll them back in).

Comment: @sime, That's an abnormal way to look at it. If you are squeezing the div between the small window area, it will center both top and bottom leaving the top cutoff. This is how vertical centering works. The proper way is to test div height exceeding window's height is by setting div height to 2000px for example.

Comment: @Hussein Yes, the top will be cut off... and more importantly, the user is not able to display the top at all - it is permanently hidden. This is an issue if the DIV has a dynamic height. For a small height, it will work, but for a large height, the top will be cut off.

Comment: @sime, Even if the height is dynamic, it will adjust and will not cut off. Try this  http://jsfiddle.net/Nt5PU/4/. In your case your are are forcing the top to cut off by squeezing and changing the window height rather then change the div height. The behavior in in your case is normal. Dynamic div height will change the div height not window height.

Comment: @Hussein You're right. The DIV won't be cut off if its height changes dynamically. However, the DIV will be cut of if its initial dimensions are larger than the viewport.

Comment: @sime, again that's not true. I have set initial dimension to 1000px which exceeds windows height http://jsfiddle.net/Nt5PU/5/ .

Comment: @Hussein If you set the initial height to 1000px, then you have to also set the margin-top to -500px (as your answer instructs). In that case the top will be cut off: http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/Nt5PU/6/ Same goes for width: if you set the width to be 800px and margin-left to -400px, and the viewport is less than 800px wide, then the left will be cut of: http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/Nt5PU/7/

Comment: @sime, Yes in that case if you need to do more dynamic things or calculations of any sort, css is not a dynamic language, javaScript will be needed. You can't dynamically make `margin-height` change value using just CSS. That is obvious. Anything more then what i provided here is getting away from the real question which is how to center an element both horizontally and vertically.

Comment: @sime, In addition, OP did not mentioned anything about dynamically loading elements with different dimensions. Otherwise the solution would've involved JavaScript. I don't know why we we discussing dynamic content here.

Comment: @Hussein But my last response was not about dynamic content at all. I was addressing the issue where the initial width/height is wider than the viewport width/height. The two demos from my last response address this. Look here: http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/Nt5PU/9/ - here we have `width:800px; margin-left:-400px;` If the viewport width is smaller than 800px, the left side of the DIV will be cut off.

Comment: @sime In your case we do not need to do horizontal centering. Beats the purpose.

Comment: @HUssein That depends on the viewport width or the user. In most cases the viewport width will be larger than 800px and in those cases you do want to center horizontally. But in some cases the viewport width of the user will be smaller than 800px - in those cases the left edge of the DIV will be cut off.

Answer (score 5):

Roger Johansson wrote an interesting article about it here: http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201103/flexible_height_vertical_centering_with_css_beyond_ie7/

Heres the gist of it:

```
<body>
    <div id="body">
        Content goes here
    </div>
</body>
```

With this css:

```
html, body { width:100%; height:100%; }
html { display:table; }
body {display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; }
#body { max-width:50em; margin:0 auto; }
```

Comment: The table method causes problems with IE 7 and before.

Comment: That's okay, @Nathan G; I don't think I care much for those browser versions anyway. :-) But thanks for the info

Answer (score 1):

For centering a line of text, set its CSS [`line-height`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_dim_line-height.asp) attribute to the same  height as the block containing it.

Comment: Mozilla is a better source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/line-height W3Schools has issues:http://w3fools.com/

Comment: I agree; W3schools does have issues, but it's still plenty helpful

Answer (score 0):

Hey its painful, yes it is. Its stupid that HTML does not by default have these things built in and even in HTML5 one has to use the same hacks. But try these solutions you will less regret to re-invent everything http://intensivstation.ch/en/templates/