# making an overlay sit perfectly centeral on any size screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an element that I need to position horizontally and vertically central on screen, I don't doing this with jQuery, but how would I go about it, currently my code looks like this,

```
$("dd a, dt a, .job_listings a, #similar_jobs a").live("click", function(){
    var self = $(this);
    $("#overlay").fadeIn('slow');
    var targetProcent = 68;
    var targetWidth = $(window).width() * (targetProcent / 100);
    var targetHeight = $(window).height() * (targetProcent / 100);   
    var targetX = ($(window).width() - 827) / 2;
    var targetY = 75;
    $('#lightbox').load(self.attr("href"));
    //usePointFromPostcode(document.getElementById('postcode').value, placeMarkerAtPoint)
    $('#lightbox').css({
        "position": "absolute", 
        "top": $(window)+75+"px", 
        "left": targetX+"px"
    }).fadeIn('slow');
    //$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

@udders; may be you can define `position :absolute` to you element
**css**

```
div{
width:300px;
height:300px;
top:50%;
left:50%;
margin-top:-150px;
margin-left:-150px;
}
```

give `margin` half of the element `height & width`

check thess links for more:

[Centering things Vertically (and Horizontally)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293121/centering-things-vertically-and-horizontally)

[Centering page content vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282758/centering-page-content-vertically)

Comment: Yup, exactly what I was thinking. Then just fade that in with jQuery, if you want to do that. And if the window gets resized, the div is moved for you. Much better than doing it yourself in code.

Comment: looks like he wants dynamic width and height though